# How do I search a sorted, huge, direct buffer efficiently in Java?

Tags: java, search, buffer

I have a direct buffer holding Integers that are already sorted (i.e. 1,1,3,3,3,3,7,7,....). Most values will occur multiple times. I want to find the first position of values I search for.

1. Is there a search functionality directly working of buffers
   built-into Java? (couldn't find anything)
2. If not, is there any decent library providing such functionality?
3. If not, what search algorithm would recommend for implementation, given that:

   - I will typically have millions of entries in my buffer
   - Speed is very important
   - It **must** return the first occurrence of the searched number
   - I'd rather not have it modify the data as I will need the original data afterwards

**EDIT:** Thanks to all the posters suggesting `Arrays.binarySearch()`, but, as far as I know, direct buffers do not generally have a backing array. That's why I was looking for an implementation that directly works on the buffer.

Also, each value can occur up to a thousand times, therefore a linear search after finding a landing point might not be very efficient. The comparator suggestion of dasblinkenlight might work though.

Comment: Would `Arrays.binarySearch` do the trick? With millions of entries, it should get you your answer in less than thirty steps. You may need to supply a custom comparator to get the first position rather than the last one.

Comment: I would use a binary search to find a number, then start a lineal search to the left until get the first occurrence of that number

Comment: @dasblinkenlight only use of binarySearch will never work. Because here the numbers are duplicated and the asker wants the first occurance of the number.

Comment: @ChandraSekhar It would, if you supply a custom comparator that compares "backward" (i.e. says "less" instead of "greater than").

Comment: @Chandra - an approach could be to use a binary search to find a landing point, then scan backwards in the buffer to find the first occurrence.

Comment: Whenever you see the phrases "linear search" and "sorted input" in one sentence, alarm bells should ring.

Comment: If you have lots of repeated values, it may be more efficient to store the data as (value, count)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best approach would be to code your own implementation of [Binary Search](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Binary_search#Java) for the buffers. This approach carefully avoids potential performance hits associated with creating views, copying large arrays etc., and stays compact at the same time.

The code sample at the link returns the rightmost point; you need to replace `>` with `>=` on the `nums[guess] > check` line to get the leftmost point. This saves you potentially costly backward linear search, or using a "backward" `Comparator`, which requires wrapping your `int` into `Integer` objects.

Comment: Thanks. If there is no library where this is already implemented, that is what I will do.

Comment: @SeNorm There are several libraries where it is already implemented, but the little tweaks required to adapt it to a `Buffer` may substantially impair the performance. Since the implementation is only a dozen lines long, there's a nearly zero cost to "go custom" and save big.

Comment: And if performance is indeed as critical as you said in the question, that's a good enough justification for "reinventing the wheel".

Answer (score 2):

Use [Binary search algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm)

```
ByteBuffer buffer = createByteBuffer();
IntBuffer intBuffer = buffer.asIntBuffer();
```

If byte array can be converted to int array use:

```
int [] array = intBuffer.array();
int index = java.util.Arrays.binarySearch(array,7);
```

Comment: You may want to mention that `intBuffer.array()` is an optional operation.

Comment: That would require an additional reverse linear  search to get the start of the sequence since the binary search doesn't guarantee to return the first element.

Comment: See java.util.Arrays.binarySearch - You can use this code to your. replace array[i] with intBuffer.get(i)

Comment: ajozwik: thanks. I'd rather avoid doing that myself if there is a solid implementation out there, but as a last resort this is what I will do.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about a built-in functionality for buffers (`Arrays.binarySearch(...)` would require you to convert the buffer to an array) but as for 3.: since the buffer is already sorted a binary search might be useful. If you found the value you could then check the previous values to get the start of that sequence.

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably have to write your own binary search: one that always moves to the left if the value checked is equal to the one searched.

So effectively instead of `x`, you're going to search for `x-ε`. Your algorithm will always take exactly logn (or logn+1) steps, as it will always "fail", but it will give you the index of the first element that is bigger than `x-ε`. All you need to do is check if that element is `x`, and if it is, you've found your match, if it isn't, there's no `x` in your buffer.